# Get Constant data from firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get a constant value from firebase?

I'm maintaining a global count variable of number of friends a user has. Everytime user wants to add friends I need to increment that variable. How can I achieve this.

If I use a OnDataChangeListener() I will be able to read the DataSnapShot only when there is some change in data. But I want to read the data even when some part of the data has not changed.

Comment: `OnDataChangeListener` will be triggered one time when you add the listener. So you don't need to wait until data changes

Comment: yeah, thanks for the help. I'm able to retrieve it by using it. Thank you.

Comment: I added it as an answer. Consider marking it as accepted, thanks

Comment: From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events): "You can use the onDataChange() method to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event. This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnDataChangeListener` will be triggered one time when you add the listener.
So you don't need to wait until data changes, try using it.